# Don’t lose even last zero of decimal value

Tags: objective-c, decimal, nsnumberformatter

Currently I have string inputs that look like: `16904.48`, `9324.00`, `6806.10`

I want my client to output: `16,904.48`, `9,324.00`, `6806.10`

I have written the following code:

```
-(NSString*)methodChangeNumberFormat:(NSString*)strGivenValue {

    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

    NSNumber *nsNumTmp = [numberFormatter numberFromString:strGivenValue];

    NSString *strNumFormatted = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:nsNumTmp];
    strNumFormatted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@",strNumFormatted];
    NSLog(@"formattedNumberString: %@", strNumFormatted);

    return strNumFormatted;
}
```

Result: `16,904.48`,  `9,324`,  `6,806.1`

But this isn't what I want, please help me to get expected result.

Now, am following input as `NSString`. But I am ready to change the input to any data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a number formatter style that does what it looks like you're trying to accomplish. Try using `NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle`.

```
- (NSString *)methodChangeNumberFormat:(NSString*)strGivenValue {
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

    // Set decimal style and read given value
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSNumber *numberFromString = [numberFormatter numberFromString:strGivenValue];

    // Set currency style and produce formatted value
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    NSString *strNumFormatted = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:numberFromString];
    NSLog(@"formattedNumberString: %@", strNumFormatted);

    return strNumFormatted;
}
```

Output:

```
formattedNumberString: $16,904.48
formattedNumberString: $9,324.00
formattedNumberString: $6,806.10
```

Comment: NSNumber *numberFromString = [numberFormatter numberFromString:strGivenValue]; ----> causing nil in iOS 7 only not in simulator. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the properties of the number formatter.

```
[numberFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
[numberFormatter setGroupingSize:3];
[numberFormatter setGroupingSeparator:@","];
```